# Can't login to Mac App store

Tags: macos, icloud, mac-appstore, apple-id

I have an iMac with Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion). When I open the Mac App store, and try to download an App, it asks me for the login. When I enter my Apple ID's email and password and click login, the button become gray for a moment, and then asks me for the credentials again. There is no error message displayed. The email and passwords are correct, since if I try an incorrect password it tells me that it is wrong.

Comment: Do you observe the same behavior when logging in to the App Store WITHOUT downloading an app or does it work then?  If  that works, can you get your App Store account information to show as well?

Comment: Try signing out completely - Store menu > Sign out. Then back in again.

Comment: @Phoenix It behave in the same way if I try to login without downloading anything

Comment: @Tetsujin I've tried, same result

Comment: Is date and time on your mac correct? Incorrect time can lead to strange timeout behaviours

Comment: @KevinGrabher Sure, it's correct

Comment: Have you tried signing in from a different user account but with the same Apple ID credentials? Helps to eliminate a user-specific problem or more global system issue.

Comment: @StuartH I didn't understand well, you're saying to create another account in the computer, and try to login to App store from that account?

Comment: @fas, yes, that's exactly it. Create a new account in System Preferences, switch to that account, and then try to log in to the App Store.

Comment: @StuartH Nothing, doesn't work

Comment: @fas go to http://appleid.apple.com and try to sign in there. If you cannot sign in there, there is a problem with your Apple ID. If you can sign in, then we know there's a problem on your machine.

Comment: @StuartH From the site I can login normally, the machine is just formatted, I didn't install anything yet

Comment: @fas, can you log in to the iTunes Store through iTunes? I've seen this happen very rarely where there are new terms and conditions to accept but the App Store doesn't properly redirect you.

Comment: @StuartH I've successfully logged into Itunes Store from iTunes but I can't succed in login in the App store yet

Comment: @fas Can you access your account info through the iTunes Store? Just taking you through the usual steps we would have used at the help desk. (: Sometimes it lets you log in but when you try to access account info, it asks you to review the new terms and conditions.

Comment: @StuartH Yes, it opens the account info page (from the menu Store->Show account info) and also asked me the payment info and I inserted them, but nothing regarding terms and conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved installing the manual updates for Mountain Lion from [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1676?locale=it_IT&viewlocale=it_IT), and then it began to work normally!

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I couldn't login to the Mac App Store or iCloud. It also wouldn't let me sign-out. It would just get stuck loading, nothing would happen and I would be asked to login again

**My solution:**

1. Go to Settings > Users and Groups and create a new admin account
2. Logout of your account
3. Login as your new admin account
4. Go to Settings > Users and Groups and change the password of your main account
5. Sign-out of your new admin account, log in to your main account and give it another go

When I was looking there were lots of complicated solutions involved in resetting NVRAM, deleting files and caches stored in /library but this is what did the trick.

Good luck!